# Длина массива в Twig

Tags: php, twig

Добрый день.
Есть проблема, у меня есть массив с заданиями. Содержит задания которые касаются непосредственно меня(для моего исполнения), а также задания, которые я заказал.

Мне нужно подсчитать колличество заданий, что я должен выполнить, и колличество заданий, что для меня должны выполнить.

Так выглядит петля for для моих заданий:

```
{% for task in tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.perfomer.id == app.user.id) %} вывод задания {% endfor %}
```

Так выглядит петля для моих заказов:

```
{% for task in tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.mentor.id == app.user.id) and task.perfomer.id != app.user.id %} вывод задания {% endfor %}
```

И вот перед каждой петлей мне нежно подсчитать по сколько заданий находится в каждом "массиве".
т.е. что то вроде: `{{ (tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.perfomer.id == app.user.id))|length }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Циклы в twig содержат в себе переменную loop.

```
{% for task in tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.perfomer.id == app.user.id) %}
    {% if loop.first %}Количество: {{ loop.length }}{% endif %}
    вывод задания
{% endfor %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

**UPD:**

Мне кажется, их тогда вообще стоило разбить на два массива заранее. А еще лучше было бы в представление передавать уже готовые переменные. Ну раз уж вопрос такой, то вот:

```
{% set tasksIn, tasksOut = [], [] %}
{% for task in tasks %}
    {% if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.perfomer.id == app.user.id) %}
        {% set tasksIn = tasksIn|merge([task]) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.mentor.id == app.user.id) and task.perfomer.id != app.user.id %}
        {% set tasksOut = tasksOut|merge([task]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

Назначенные мне: {{ tasksIn|length }}
{% for task in tasksIn %}Вывод{% endfor %}

Назначенные мной: {{ tasksOut|length }}
{% for task in tasksOut %}Вывод{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, здесь не подсчитывается колличество заданий. Вот результат выполнения:
array:4 [▼
  "parent" => array:4 [▶]
  "index0" => 0
  "index" => 1
  "first" => true
]. Мне нужно посчитать именно колличество заданий, но перед этой петлей.

Comment: @Владислав Добавил

Comment: Спасибо, думаю лучше заранее на массиввы разделю и уже в передам в представление. Я именно хотел избежать повторяющейся петли. Спасибо за ответ. Твиг недавно осваивать начал, думал на все своя пиплюля будет :)

Answer (score 2):

В принятом ответе twig используется как язык программирования для построения массивов. Не совсем подходящая задача для шаблонизатора. В идеале, конечно, сборку массивов лучше перенести в php. Но если это невозможно, то можно применить другое решение, без создания новых массивов.

Для этого нужно использовать [`set`/`endset`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html#set):

```
{% set tasksIn, tasksOut = 0, 0 %}

{% set tasksIn_content %}
    {% for task in tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.perfomer.id == app.user.id) %}
        {% set tasksIn = loop.index %}
        вывод задания 
    {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

{% set tasksOut_content %}
    {% for task in tasks if (task.deadline > "now"|date(datetime_type)) and (task.mentor.id == app.user.id) and task.perfomer.id != app.user.id %}
       {% set tasksOut = loop.index %}
        вывод задания
    {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

Количество: {{ tasksIn }}, {{ tasksOut }}

Назначенные мне: {{ tasksIn_content }}
Назначенные мной: {{ tasksOut_content }}
```

То есть, сам ваш цикл остается неизменным, добавляется только обертка и назначение переменной внутри цикла.

Этот подход более универсальный, так как его также можно использовать, если внутри цикла нужно посчитать несколько счетчиков (например, сколько заданий было выполненных, сколько заняло больше 5 часов времени) и вывести эти счетчики ДО самого списка заданий.

Comment: да, именно так я сначала и сделал. Но потом оказалось, что я сначала должен посчитать колличество, а потом пускать петлю. По сути проще всего сделать  как вы пишите, и посредством JS позднее добавить результат в положеное место.